# Change each letter of the sentence/word to something specific

Tags: python

I would like to replace each letter of the sentence entered by the user with something specific.

I tried it with the "replace" function, but the code is way too long, because I don't know how to make lowercase and uppercase letters in one, so the code doesn't get too long. Furthermore, I want a "+" sign between the new letters, but not at the beginning and end

```
a = 'new_a'
b = 'new_b'
c = 'new_c'
d = 'new_d'
e = 'new_e'
f = 'new_f'
g = 'new_g'
h = 'new_h'
i = 'new_i'
j = 'new_j'
k = 'new_k'
l = 'new_l'
m = 'new_m'
n = 'new_n'
o = 'new_o'
p = 'new_p'
q = 'new_q'
r = 'new_r'
s = 'new_s'
t = 'new_t'
u = 'new_u'
v = 'new_v'
w = 'new_w'
x = 'new_x'
y = 'new_y'
z = 'new_z'

input_string = input("Text: ")

new_string = input_string.replace('a', a).replace('b', b).replace('c', c).replace('d', d).replace('e', e)...

print(new_string)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a regular expression replacement with a callback function that looks up the replacements in a dictionary.

```
import re

replacements = {'a': 'new_a', 'b': 'new_b', ..., 'A': 'new_A', 'B': 'new_B', ...}
new_string = re.sub('[a-z]', lambda match: replacements[match.group()], input_string)
```

Note that your code has other problems besides being repetitive. If the input string is

```
abc
```

the replacement of `a`, `b`, and `c` will produce

```
new_anew_bnew_c
```

Then the replacement of `e` will produce

```
nnew_ew_annew_ew_bnnew_ew_c
```

and when it gets to `n` it will become

```
new_nnew_new_ew_anew_nnew_new_ew_bnew_nnew_new_ew_c
```

and the final result after replacing the `w` will be:

```
nenew_w_nnenew_w_nenew_w_enew_w_anenew_w_nnenew_w_nenew_w_enew_w_bnenew_w_nnenew_w_nenew_w_enew_w_c
```

Comment: But if the user now enters the capital letter "A", then it is not replaced. I want that no matter if the user uses small or capital letters, that they are replaced by the predefined ones

Comment: Your code doesn't handle uppercase letters, either. Add the uppercase letters to the dictionary.

Comment: @ALLTON Simply use @Barmar's code but with `input_string.lower()` instead, which converts `input_string` to lowercase. This makes the solution case-agnostic.

Comment: I think we are talking past each other. So, I want the letter a and A to be replaced by "new_a", I want to determine that above "a = new_a".

new_a is simply a placeholder in the example, at the end there should be something else. Furthermore, as described above, there should be a "+" between the new letters.

Example:

User enters: abc 
Output should be: new_a+new_b+new_c

Even if the user enters "ABC", the output should be the same.

Comment: You can do what the above comment said, convert the input to lowercase first. Or you can put the same replacement for both `a` and `A` in the dictionary.

Comment: If you also want to have a separator, you should convert the input to a list, perform the replacements on the list elements, then use `'+'.join(result)` to create the concatenated string. But that's not in the question.